# Approval of an app that basically displays a web page optimized for mobile

Tags: app-store, appstore-approval

Does anyone know if they allow an app that more or less shows a mobile optimized web page through an iframe (using Phonegap), where you have to log in as it is a members-only application?

If not, is there any other strategies that would work for an only-member application like this were the members DO NOT pay the membership fee through the App Store?

Answer (score 1):

As of App Store Review Guidelines, 2.12:

`2.12 - Apps that are not very useful, are simply web sites bundled as apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected`

So the answer is *no, your app will not be easily approved*. Since it is a human review, it could get approved anyway, but chances are that your app won't ever be approved.

A simple strategy that Apple recommends is generating a web app. That is basically a view of your website adapted to your device that you share through the Internet instead of through the App Store (more info from Apple here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html).

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer Injuanj. I suspect you are right. What I am afraid of is that users are going to avoid using the app when they have to log in manually all the time. 

So my new strategy is to make a free app with some content (stored in the app itself), but with the option to log in as a member in the app. When the user do sign in, the full app is shown through an iframe with all the functionality available. The next time the user uses the app, the login details is stored in the app itself and will then automatically get the full app...

Thanks again for your help!

Fredrik

Comment: You may do that. It sounds like a good approach. Don't forget to give the reviewer a *demo* functional account, since it is necessary, when you submit your app (there is a place for that in iTunes Connect).